# how to plot a only one variable with its mean and sd

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, mean, standard-deviation

I am very new to plotting. sorry for the dummy question.
I want to plot only one variable. The mean is (mean= 51.9187) and the sd is (sd= 30.94052).
first of all which plot is the best option (line plot or dot plot)? and how to plot it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to plot only one variable, you should use an histogram plot in order to see the distribution. I created some fake data assuming your variable has a normal distribution.

```
set.seed(2021)
vector_data <- rnorm(100,51.9187,30.94052)
hist(vector_data)
```

[image]